# will_paginate gem boot_strap issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, rubygems

I'm working on rails app. every thing was fine until i start using will_paginate, the issue is bootstrap for will paginate is not working properly, until i include "@import bootstrap" in my application.scss.css file. But when i do this, my all other bootstrap styles are changed. Your help will be highly appreciated.

- I have added these gems

  gem 'devise'
  gem 'devise-bootstrap-views'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem "font-awesome-rails"
  gem 'devise-i18n'
  gem 'activestorage', '~> 6.1', '>= 6.1.3.1'
  gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 7.0'
  gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 1.0.0'
- here is my application.scss.css file

  /*

  - This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
  - listed below.
  - 
  - Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
  - vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
  - 
  - You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
  - compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
  - files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
  - It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
    *`
    *= require font-awesome
    *= require bootstrap
    *= require_tree .
    *= require_self

  */

-this syntax i am using for will_paginate in my views

```
<%= will_paginate @admin_products, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

this is my controller action

```
def index
    @admin_products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:3)
  end
```

here is my github repo
https://github.com/qazi-nxb/shopify.git

Comment: Hi. Please be more precise in the question. One way is to copy paste the keyword in your error message.
Please be carefull to the format of your post : we can't see the gems. we can't see application.scss.css
Furthermore, "here is my github repo " sounds like "I have a problem, solve my problem !" Please help us to help you :) give anything in the post and prevent us to click on any link, we prefer to stay on stack overflow to answer you

Comment: hey @Hettomei My apologies, I am new here, it's my first question. I don't know a lot about procedure & styling.

Comment: The issue is I'm not getting any error message, i have styling issues. my pagination bar is not styled according to bootstrap views.